# Finding intersection points between a contour and a line with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I upload an image and let the Canny algorithm detect the contours. Then I draw a line in the image and want to find the intersection points of the line and the largest contour.
In some pixel rows this procedure works without problems, in others not at all.

Here are some pictures visualizing my problem (first picture with intersection points, second without, third is the original image, fourth the tilted image) and below my code so far:

Image 1:[image]

Image 2:[image]

Original Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQYMZ.jpg)

Tilted Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKTJj.jpg)

---

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the picture
img_path = 'path'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Extract contours
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the image to create a binary image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 100, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Apply Canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)

# Find contour points and assign them to pixel rows
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
rows, cols = img.shape[:2]
pixel_counts = [0] * cols
for cnt in contours:
    for point in cnt:
        row, col = point[0]
        pixel_counts[col] += 1

# Find pixel row with the most contour points
max_count = max(pixel_counts)
max_col = pixel_counts.index(max_count) - 50

# Draw line
cv2.line(img, (0, max_col), (cols-1, max_col), (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Threshold the image a second time to create a binary image better suited for contour
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Apply Canny edge detection a second time
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)

# Find contours in the binary image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find the contour with the largest area (which is assumed to be the bubble)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Fit a polynom to the largest contour
epsilon = 0.0001 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)

# Draw the polynom fit in yellow
cv2.polylines(img, [approx], True, (0, 255, 255), 2)

# Convert line points to numpy array
line_points = np.array([(0, max_col), (cols-1, max_col)])

# Find intersection of line and largest contour
if len(cnt) > 0:
    intersection_points = []
    for i in range(len(cnt)):
        x, y = cnt[i][0]
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(line_points, (x, y), True)

        if dist == 0:
            intersection_points.append((x, y))
        

else:
    print("Error: No contour points found")
    exit()

# Draw intersection points in green
for point in intersection_points:
    cv2.circle(img, point, 4, (0, 255, 0), thickness=-1)
```

I want to be able to use this method for all pixel rows.

Comment: We need your 2 original images for problem analysis.

Comment: I can't see any difference between the two images that you have shared until now.

Comment: @Markus In the second one the red line is 2 pixels higher, and the 2 green dots where yellow appears to intersect the red are missing.

Comment: I think the root of the problem lies in your incorrect assumption that the contour will have a vertex on every row/column. That's not necessarily the case with `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`. Try it with `CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`. But yeah, it's hard to say if you don't provide sample inputs.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you very much for your answers so far! I have edited my question and provided the original image and the tilted image (tilted by 60 degrees).
@Markus, like Dan said, in the second picture the red line is 2 pixels higher. In this case no intersections (green dots) between the red line and the yellow contour are detected. I cant get behind why no interesection points are detected once i am shifting the line 2 pixels up.

Comment: @DanMašek you just solved the problem and saved my evening. Thank you so much!!